# How do I connect SQL Server with IBM JDK 8?

Tags: java, ibm-jdk

My application run on Suse Linux with IBM JDK 8.
The code is

```
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx:1433;DatabaseName", "user", "password");
        Statement sta=con.createStatement();
        String sql="select * from table";
```

The problem is

> The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed

If I change the jdk from IBM to Oracle ,the application will be run .
How do I connect sqlserver with IBM JDK?

> java version "1.8.0" 
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6480sr3fp12-20160919_01(SR3 FP12)) 
>   IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20160915_318796 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) 
>   J9VM - R28_Java8_SR3_20160915_0912_B318796 
>   JIT  - tr.r14.java.green_20160818_122998 
>   GC   - R28_Java8_SR3_20160915_0912_B318796_CMPRSS 
>   J9CL - 20160915_318796) 
>   JCL - 20160914_01 based on Oracle jdk8u101-b13

Comment: do you know the specific Java version of each?  Maybe you could try a jvm argument such as -Dhttps.protocols

Comment: @BrandonG my application run on a Suse Linux OS with a IBM JDK installed, but   it's not my own JVM

Answer (score 0):

add a tls version 
jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx:1433;DatabaseName=databasename;**sslProtocol=TLSv1.2**

Comment: Why?  How does it fix it?  Why does it fix it?  What was the actual problem?

Comment: @StephenC I am really sorry , I dont know the true reason. But it really works.Maybe the sqlserver 2014 must be connected with v1.2, but the ibm jdk use an old version default